# mysql - count null and non-null fields in one query

Tags: mysql

Input table (named `ruchin`)

```
id     comment           order_id          deleted_at
1        abc               1234              NULL
2        abcd              1234              TimeStamp
3        xyz               1234              NULL
4        pqr               1234              TimeStamp
5        as                4567               NULL
6        lo                4567               NULL
```

and I want output as

```
order_id        count(deleted_at==Timestamp)    count(deleted_at==NULL)
1234                   2                                 2
4567                   0                                  2
```

and I want this to be in single query.How can I do this???

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `count()` for that, since it doesn't count `NULL` values.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT order_id, 
       count(deleted_at) as 'del is not null',
       count(order_id) - count(deleted_at) as 'del is NULL' 
FROM ruchin 
GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: Here NULL is the parameter,it doesn't means actual NULL,consider NULL as variable x.